# Transcoding a video from GoToMeeting WMV to MP4 using FFMPEG on Windows locks up dos window

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I've been tasked with converting some pre-recorded GoToMeeting videos from wmv to mp4 format. I've got the GoToMeeting transcoder app available from Citrix (g2mtranscoder.exe) that takes the source wmv and makes it so that ffmpeg can work with the wmv. The problem I have is when I then try and take that wmv and transcode it to mp4.

I'm using the latest pre-compiled static version of ffmpeg for Windows from here http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Here is the command line I'm using to begin the conversion:

```
"C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "999_1366_768_g2m_transcoded.wmv" -f "mp4" -b "1000k" -r "30" -ab "128k" -ar "22050" -s "1366x768" -strict "experimental" -y "999.mp4"
```

Here is FFMPEG's output. The last line is where the dos window seems to stop executing/locks up (when I say lock up I mean just the dos window is locked up, not the entire machine):

```
ffmpeg version N-31932-g41bf67d, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers built on Aug 16 2011 18:54:12 with gcc 4.6.1
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-memalign-hack --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil    51. 12. 0 / 51. 12. 0
  libavcodec   53. 10. 0 / 53. 10. 0
  libavformat  53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0
  libavdevice  53.  3. 0 / 53.  3. 0
  libavfilter   2. 31. 1 /  2. 31. 1
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[asf @ 01BBB600] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5194000

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 59.92 (719/12)
Input #0, asf, from 'D:\Inetpub\g2m\Transcoding\999_1366_768_g2m_transcoded.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.4007
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 4403
    Buffer Average  : 1470
    WM/ToolVersion  : 4.8 Build 723
    WM/ToolName     : GoToMeeting
    BitRateFrom the writer: 1553
    Audio samples   : 6221
    Video samples   : 3455
    recording time  : Mon, 22 Aug 2011 11:48:42 Eastern Daylight Time
  Duration: 00:38:30.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 48 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3 (Main), yuv420p, 1366x768, 2154 kb/s, 59.92 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[buffer @ 01BBC120] w:1366 h:768 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
Output #0, mp4, to '\\nas4\FMS_APPLICATIONS\SVC\sk12\webinars\999.mp4':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.4007
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 4403
    Buffer Average  : 1470
    WM/ToolVersion  : 4.8 Build 723
    WM/ToolName     : GoToMeeting
    BitRateFrom the writer: 1553
    Audio samples   : 6221
    Video samples   : 3455
    recording time  : Mon, 22 Aug 2011 11:48:42 Eastern Daylight Time
    encoder         : Lavf53.7.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1366x768, q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  149 fps= 63 q=23.5 size=    1103kB time=00:00:04.96 bitrate=1818.6kbits/s dup=144 drop=0
```

Does anyone have any idea why it's locking up the dos window and essentially failing to convert the file to mp4? I had a friend test it on a linux box and he was able to convert the video just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got an overclocked system?

Comment: @Sandeep - No, the machine in question is not over clocked.